# How to inititiate tasks in celery for a websocket request in tornado?

Tags: websocket, celery, tornado

I'm currently using the software stack as: Tornado (Websockethandler) + Celery(Task Manager) + RabbitMQ (amqp) + Redis as the backend.

However I am not able to integrate the Tornado and celery for websocket requests. Can we have some pointers/ examples for it?

Note I have used CeleryMixin and Tcelery. Doesn't work well for me.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

https://github.com/mher/tornado-celery allows to call Celery tasks from Tornado

```
from tornado import gen, web
import tcelery, tasks

tcelery.setup_nonblocking_producer()

class AsyncHandler(web.RequestHandler):
    @asynchronous
    def get(self):
        tasks.echo.apply_async(args=['Hello world!'], callback=self.on_result)

    def on_result(self, response):
        self.write(str(response.result))
        self.finish()
```

Comment: Doesn't allow me to use it with the WebSocket Handler.